# Export excel funciton javascript, want to keep 0 on phone column

Tags: javascript, excel

```
function fnExcelReport_pfn() {
        var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
        tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';

        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

        tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
        tab_text = tab_text + $('#myTable').html();
        tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                    type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                });
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'myexcel.xls');
            }
        } else {

            $('#persoane_fizice_nefinalizate').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
            $('#pf').attr('download', 'commands' + timestamp() + '.xls');

        }

    }
```

I have the next code for exporting a table in excel, and I have column with phone numbers. For expample, I have the phone number: 0123456789 what I have before expor is  123456789. What can I do to keep the 0?